I can't override the entrypoint or CMD from a specific image
I'm trying to add a custom script to add some custom hosts to my docker image (cant use --add-host).
I'm trying to add that script to my image that extends MinIO image on startup but no matter what I try, my script don't run.
I even tried to leave the entrypoint and cmd empty to at least see if it's being overwritten but the entrypoint and cmd still persists from the MinIO image.
I tried to follow this post: Docker - extend the parent's ENTRYPOINT
Here's what I tried so far in my Dockerfile:
FROM minio/minio:RELEASE.2024-07-15T19-02-30Z
# build custom script
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh" >> setup.sh
RUN echo "echo 192.168.0.123 custom.domain.example >> /etc/hosts" >> setup.sh
RUN echo "minio" >> setup.sh
RUN chmod +x setup.sh

ENTRYPOINT [] # Not even leaving it empty does anything
CMD ["./setup.sh"] # Not even leaving it empty does anything

Why the entrypoint and cmd doesn't get overwritten?

Why do you think your script isn't getting run?  What are the exact commands you're running to build and run this image?  (You shouldn't usually need to touch /etc/hosts at all, but if you do, consider the docker run --add-host option.)

why did you say you can't use --add-host, @Thalles Passos?

@DavidMaze because nothing is written to the /etc/hosts, I even tried adding some "echo debug" lines but nothing is sent to the console and also when I set an empty entrypoint and cmd the image still starts normally as nothing happened and I cant use the -add-host because I dont have access to the docker run command.

@EmmanuelMurairi Unfortunately I dont have access to the docker run command, I'm running a custom docker panel on top of Docker which dont provide that functionality yet.

...are you actually sure you're running your modified image?

@DavidMaze Yes, I can see the setup.sh file created when opening a terminal inside the container.
